# pyopengl How to render text

Tags: python, opengl, glut, pyopengl

I use this function to render text, but the first parameter will report an error. I don't know how to use it

[image]

```
glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, "text to render")
  ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument of `glutBitmapCharacter`  is an integral number representing one character. You have to use a `for`-loop to write a string and convert each character with [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord):

```py
for c in text:
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, ord(c))
```

When using `glutBitmapString`, the argument must be a string in binary format (`b"text to render"`). e.g.:

```py
text = b"Hello World"
glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, text)
```

or [`encdode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) the string

```py
text = "Hello World"
glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, text.encode('ascii'))
```

---

Minimal example:

```py
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

def text(x, y, color, text):
    glColor3fv(color)
    glWindowPos2f(x, y)

    #for c in text:
    #    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, ord(c))

    glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, text.encode('ascii'))

def display():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    text(100, 100, (1, 0, 0), "Hello World!")
    glutSwapBuffers()
    glutPostRedisplay()

glutInit(sys.argv)
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA)
glutInitWindowSize(400, 200)
glutCreateWindow(b"OpenGL Window")
glutDisplayFunc(display)
glutMainLoop()
```